# How do additional regressors and seasonality get incorporated into fbprophet?

Tags: time-series, prophet

I've been playing around with fbprophet [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html) and I've noticed they specify their base additive model is

$$y(t) = g(t) + s(t) + h(t) + \epsilon_t$$

My question is two-fold:

1) How does modifying the `seasonality_mode='multiplicative'` affect the model? does the equation become

$$y(t) = g(t)\times s(t) + h(t) + \epsilon_t$$
or 
$$y(t) = g(t)\times s(t) \times h(t) + \epsilon_t$$
or something completely different?

2) If I add an additional regressor, $r$, does the equation become
$$y(t) = g(t) + s(t) + h(t) + \alpha r + \epsilon_t$$
where $\alpha$ is some coefficient that is fitted to the value of $r$
or 
$$y(t) = g(t) + s(t) + h(t) + f(r) + \epsilon_t$$
where $f(r)$ is a function that is constructed similarly to $g(t)$?

I couldn't find much in the paper or in the documentation to explain how these modifications actually change the underlying model